# 2-player Lord of the Rings game from the early 2000s

Tags: identify-this-game

I am looking for a LOTR 2-player (1v1) board game I received for Christmas as a kid in the early 2000s (after the last movie got released, so probably 2003 or 2004, but the game in itself may have been older).

Each player controlled 9 characters: the white player controlled the Fellowship, while the black player controlled Sauron's forces.

The game was played on a square map divided in several cells of irregular sizes and shapes, each representing a region of Middle-Earth, with the Shire and Mordor at opposite sides, which I think served at the starting points for each team.

Each character I believe possessed a special ability and a "strength" level between 1 and 9. 
The character tiles were printed with an artwork and showed the name, a description of the special ability, and the "strength". The tiles were inserted in plastic stands and placed face to their owner so that the opponent could not see which character was in which position on the board.

When 2 opposing characters were in the same region, players had to reveal them and then a battle phase started. During battle the players had to use cards but I don't remember what purpose they served.

The game ended when Frodo managed to reach Mordor (White wins) or was killed by the Enemy (Black wins).

The art style resembled *a lot* that of John Howe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like  [Lord of the Rings: The Confrontation](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3201/lord-rings-confrontation)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged.  Links can rot, and then the answer is no help to anyone who finds it.  You should edit in some information about why you think this is the correct answer -- characteristics of the game you linked to.

Comment: That's the one ! I guess I didn't search hard enough because I had found Reiner Knizia's first LOTR game but not this one. Could you please edit your answer as @ZeissIkon said, and I will accept it.

Comment: Well 2 weeks have passed; I am accepting the answer since it is the game I was looking for but an edit would still be appreciated, as the link could become invalid in the future.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm not sure adding more text will improve the answer in this case. The name of the game is the only critical information, and it's there even if link dies, everything extra just feels like bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like LOTR Stratego, the cards were exclusive special units in the LOTR edition not commonly in Stratego

Comment: One-liner answers are not very helpful.  Please edit in some information on why you think this is the correct game.